# What are my liabilities concerning my half of house my brother and I Inherited from Mom

Tags: property, inheritance

My brother and I inherited a house from my mother.  She was sick for about a year and a half before her death and he managed her care and finances during that time.  He is local and I live about 300 miles away. He has been mostly unemployed and she supported him for more than 20 years, paying his rent and most of his expenses.  I have been independent for more than 30 years.  A week before her death, he moved in with her expecting to take care of her for awhile.  I visited as often a I could but I have a family to take care of.  When Mom died she left her estate to us 50/50 including her house.  My brother and uncle were co-executors.  It's been a year, he still lives there (I don't have a problem with that) and we are both on the title of the house now. He wants to continue living there and pay off the mortgage (about $10,000) with his share of the inheritance (which isn't much).  While the will is being settled, (long story) I have loaned him 2 mortgage payments.  Recently he told me that Mom "WANTED" him to have the house but that isn't in writing and doesn't match with conversations I had with her.  Now that we both own the house, he is hinting that I owe half the expenses.  I can't and won't do that. He doesn't want to sell and can't afford to buy me out.  I don't want this to come between us because we've always been close but he has always been "entitled" and I don't want to be taken advantage of.  What are my liabilities and responsibilities concerning my share of the house? If we sell the house, can he claim more than half of the proceeds and how does that work? Can he deduct expenses and mortgage payments from my share? MANY THANKS

Answer (score 1):

Of course you have to pay half the cost. Just as your brother has to pay rent at the market rate.

If rent at market rate is $1,000 and the monthly cost (taxes, maintenance etc.) is $400, then your brother should pay $1,000 a month, the $400 is paid from rental income, and the $600 profit shared, so you get $300 and he gets $300. In total he would pay $700, $400 going to the cost, $300 in your pocket.

Instead you have been nice to him and let him live there for paying the cost ($400). If he doesn’t like it, he can pay more. Remind him that he isn’t paying rent, so if he wants all cost precisely shared then he must pay rent.

If you have no problem with him living there (he’s your brother after all) then you should also take into account that he is paying off the mortgage, once the house is sold.